# Augmenting an algorithm with a monotonic step

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, convergence-acceleration

Suppose algorithm $A$ is known to converge to the global maximum from any feasible point.

I believe it is the case that if I augment $A$ with a monotonically increasing step $B$, then the new algorithm $A'$ is guaranteed to converge to the global max as well.

Is this the case? If so, is there a reference I can cite?

Comment: What does it mean to augment an algorithm with a step? What does a "step" mean?

Comment: @StellaBiderman: by augmenting the algorithm $A$ with step $B$, I mean that $A'$ includes all the procedures done in $A$, plus a new procedure $B$ (that is insured not to decrease the objective function) in each iteration of the algorithm.

Comment: In order? So, if we think of them as functions you're just looking a $A'(x)=B(A(x))$?

Comment: @StellaBiderman: yes, that is correct

Comment: How does an algorithm converge? Are you applying $A(x)$, then $A(A(x))$, etc and that sequence converges?

Comment: @StellaBiderman: yes that is correct.

Comment: Your post is not written using normal mathematics terminology. I editted it to what I believe your question is. Can you confirm that this is the correct question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33950/discussion-between-cliff-ab-and-stella-biderman).